# ошибка в некоторых тестах python

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода

**ЗАДАНИЕ**

В одной компьютерной игре игрок выставляет в линию шарики разных цветов. Когда образуется непрерывная цепочка из трех и более шариков одного цвета, она удаляется из линии. Все шарики при этом сдвигаются друг к другу, и ситуация может повториться.

По данному расположению шариков определите, сколько шариков будет сейчас уничтожено.

**ВХОДНЫЕ ДАННЫЕ**

Программа получает на вход строку, в которой через пробел записаны цвета шариков в цепочке. Цвета обозначаются числами от 0 до 9.

**ВЫХОДНЫЕ ДАННЫЕ**

Программа должна вывести одно число — количество шариков, которое будет уничтожено.

**ПРИМЕР**

```
ввод    1 3 3 3 2
вывод   3
ввод    3 3 2 1 1 1 2 2 3 3
вывод   10
ввод    2 4 4 5 5 7
вывод   4
```

Вот мой код, проходит не все тесты. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить, или тесты, на которых будет ошибка.

```
count=0
stack=[]
a=list(map(int,input().split()))
b=max(a) + 1
C = [0] * b
for x in a:
    C[x] += 1
for elem in C:
    if elem == 0:
        C.pop(elem)
for i in range(len(C)):
    if C[i] > 1:
        count += C[i]
print(count)
```

Comment: Я добавила тест

Comment: @gil9red я так понимаю, это что-то из олимпиадных задачек, а там тесты вроде обычно скрыты

Comment: @andreymal, угу, чтобы программист не мог набить в коде условия решения каждого теста... Но прятать тесты не лучшая идея -- лучше набор тестов, которые видны, и кучу рандомных тестов

Comment: @JuliaPonomareva а, у вас тесты скрыты? Я бы в таком случае написал собственные. )

Comment: @IgorSergeevich а Вы в детском саду участвовали в олимпиадах по программированию?)

Comment: @NickVolynkin скрыты, все мои тесты проходит, а в контестере -нет

Comment: @JuliaPonomareva вероятно, у тестов покрытие неполное. Посмотреть бы на набор кейсов. Может быть, вы зададите ещё один вопрос с метками [tag:юнит-тесты] и [tag:инспекция-кода] про покрытие? Опубликуйте именно набор кейсов, без кода, например `12223`, `111222`, `112221` и т.п.

Comment: в примере `ввод    2 4 4 5 5 7` для непрерывная цепочка из `трех и более` должен быть `вывод` `0` а не `4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import itertools

min_len = 3  # мин длина для цепочки шариков одного цвета

def counter(nums: list, count=0) -> int:
    c = 0
    for num, group in itertools.groupby(nums):
        lg = len(list(group))  # длина цепочки
        c += lg
        if lg >= min_len:  # цепочка шариков одного цвета
            return counter(nums[:c-lg]+nums[c:], count+lg)  # сдвиг шариков друг к другу
    return count

a = counter('1 3 3 3 2'.split())
b = counter('3 3 2 1 1 1 2 2 3 3'.split())
c = counter('2 4 4 5 5 7'.split())
print(a, b, c)  # 3 10 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Накидал примерный алгоритм, вроде бы, даже работает. Попробуйте с ним те тесты пройти:

```
def destroy_chain_balls(balls):
    # Будет работать с копией
    balls = list(balls)

    while balls:
        repeat_index_list = [0]
        last_ball = balls[0]

        for i in range(1, len(balls)):
            ball = balls[i]

            # Наткнулись на новый тип шарика
            if last_ball != ball:
                # Если не удалось набрать последовательность, чистим список
                if len(repeat_index_list) < 3:
                    repeat_index_list.clear()
                else:
                    # Последовательность есть, прерываем цикл
                    break

            repeat_index_list.append(i)
            last_ball = ball

        # Если перебор закончился, а последовательность не была найдена,
        # заканчиваем уничтожение шариков
        if len(repeat_index_list) < 3:
            break

        # Удаляем шарики из найденной последовательности
        for i in reversed(repeat_index_list):
            balls.pop(i)

        repeat_index_list.clear()

    return balls


balls = [0, 1, 2, 3]
balls_2 = destroy_chain_balls(balls)
print("{} -> {}, уничтожено: {}".format(balls, balls_2, len(balls) - len(balls_2)))

balls = [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3]
balls_2 = destroy_chain_balls(balls)
print("{} -> {}, уничтожено: {}".format(balls, balls_2, len(balls) - len(balls_2)))

balls = [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
balls_2 = destroy_chain_balls(balls)
print("{} -> {}, уничтожено: {}".format(balls, balls_2, len(balls) - len(balls_2)))

balls = [1, 3, 3, 3, 2]
balls_2 = destroy_chain_balls(balls)
print("{} -> {}, уничтожено: {}".format(balls, balls_2, len(balls) - len(balls_2)))

balls = [1, 1, 1]
balls_2 = destroy_chain_balls(balls)
print("{} -> {}, уничтожено: {}".format(balls, balls_2, len(balls) - len(balls_2)))
```

Консоль:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3] -> [0, 1, 2, 3], уничтожено: 0
[0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3] -> [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3], уничтожено: 0
[0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3] -> [0, 1, 3], уничтожено: 6
[1, 3, 3, 3, 2] -> [1, 2], уничтожено: 3
[1, 1, 1] -> [], уничтожено: 3
```